# Annoying Cookies and View more popup appears over the Sway embed container on my webpage

Tags: office365, ms-office

When I share my **Sway presentation** via "**Get embed code**" option then it shows the **cookies use popup** in the container on my webpage where I have embedded the code. It also shows a small "**View more**" popup at the bottom which spoils all the fun :(

First of all, it gets really annoying because there is no close option.
Secondly it needs extra user interaction to close the bottom popup. :(

In my case I show it on a signage screen, hence no option to interact at all.
Has anybody faced same issue?
Is there any way to avoid this?

(It would be so better if Microsoft Sway find some option to get rid of this automatically or whichever option suits best to them)

Check attached snapshot for more info -
Annoying popup in Sway embed.png

[image]

Check on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/w7omkjgr/

```
<iframe width="760px" height="500px" src="https://sway.office.com/s/f6aQvX6oax4MBIMD/embed" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" max-width="100%" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts" scrolling="no" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100vh" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stackover flow does not have a "ms-sway"  tag. Can anybody please add it so that it will be helpful for other users (below 1500 rep) to add related questions.